# Extension $L/K$ and the field $K[a]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm not sure I fully understand what is an extension $L/K$. Is it correct to say it is a field $L$ that contains a subfield isomorphic to $K$?
Keeping this in mind, is it correct to say that considering an extension $L/K$, $K[a]$ is the smallest subring of $L$ that contains a and a subfield isomorphic to $K$?

Considering these definition, $K[a]$ is just defined up to isomorphism no?

Answer (score 1):

Actually depending on the authors you can find two definitions of a field extension : some require that $K$ is included in $L$, and some just require that there is a morphism $K\to L$ (necessarily injective).

But in the second case, the morphism is part of the data, so you can identify $K$ with a subfield of $L$ without ambiguity.